# How to define javafx callback with no prarameter

Tags: javafx, callback

I don't know how to define a callback that doesn't need any parameter. In order to describe the question, let me make up a setup - mine is different but contains several more classes, harder to digest.

Lets say we have

```
public class CustomerA {
  public Payment payWithCash() {...}
}
```

and

```
public class CustomerB {
      public Payment payWithCreditCard() {...}
}
```

and in addition

```
public abstract class Factory {
    public Callback<Void, Payment> getPaymentCallback();

    // Some other methods
    ...
}
```

then here comes the problem: I'd like to implement something like this

```
public class CashFactoryA extends Factory {
    public Callback<Void, Payment> getPaymentCallback() {
        return CustomerA::payWithCash;
    }
}
```

and in a different class

```
public class CashFactoryB extends Factory {
    public Callback<Void, Payment> getPaymentCallback() {
        return CustomerB::payWithCreditCard;
    }
}
```

What happens is, that the compiler complains, that CustomerB does not define payWithCreditCard(Void) and CustomerA likewise fails for payWithCash(Void).

So how to state this correct that there is no parameter to the Callback?

I am aware that I could probably solve my problem as well with interfaces, but I like to understand how to solve this with a Callback.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider making `Factory` generic:

```
public abstract class Factory<T> {
    public Callback<T, Payment> getPaymentCallback();

    // Some other methods
    ...
}
```

And then you can do

```
public class CashFactoryA extends Factory<CustomerA> {
    public Callback<CustomerA, Payment> getPaymentCallback() {
        return CustomerA::payWithCash;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CashFactoryB extends Factory<CustomerB> {
    public Callback<CustomerB, Payment> getPaymentCallback() {
        return CustomerB::payWithCreditCard;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James. The way I understand  the documentation is that T in the Factorybecomes the argument to the Callback, in other words, the interface for payWithCash would look like "public Payment payWithCash(CustomerA customer)", right? But then I have an argument. But I wanted to be without arguments. Or do I miss something?

Comment: No, `T` is a type parameter. Nothing in your `CustomerA` or `CustomerB` classes would change here. (Perhaps you need to post the code showing how you want to use this...?)

Comment: Hello James. I am confused. I can follow to the point that the "T" in "class Factory<T> is the type parameter. But you loose me when this "T" is reused in "public Callback<T, Payment> getPaymentCallback();
". The reason why I have a hard time to follow is that the JavaDoc for Callback says "Interface Callback<P,R>
Type Parameters:
P - The type of the argument provided to the call method.
R - The type of the return type of the call method." so I thought whatever I put after the "<" is the argument. What am I missing here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Alex I don't understand what you are asking. Does the code I suggested not work?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

**This answer is a wrong approach.**

---

First, you are trying to refer `payWithCash` from not a instance of `CustomerA` but the class `CustomerA`, so `payWithCash` must be static method.

```
public class CustomerA {
    public static Payment payWithCash() {...}
}
```

Then use lambda expression which is the same interface as your `Callback`.

```
public class CashFactoryA extends Factory {
    public Callback<Void, Payment> getPaymentCallback() {
        return param -> CustomerA.payWithCash();
    }
}
```

The code above has the same meaning as the code below. The param argument will be ignored as a result.

```
public class CashFactoryA extends Factory {
    public Callback<Void, Payment> getPaymentCallback() {
        return new Callback<Void, Payment>(){
            @Override
            public Payment call(Void param) {
                return CustomerA.payWithCash();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: *"First, you are trying to refer `payWithCash` from not a instance of `CustomerA`  but the class `CustomerA`"*. This isn't true, is it? In the context of the OP, `CustomerA::payWithCash` is equivalent to `(CustomerA customerAInstance) -> customerAInstance.payWithCash()`. In other words, the method reference refers to an instance method, that is invoked on a `CustomerA` instance.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I had totally misunderstood method reference of class method.